# CMake on Linux: "target platform does not support dynamic linking"

Tags: cmake, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I have the very simple `CMakeLists.txt`

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
FIND_PACKAGE(VTK REQUIRED)
PROJECT(test CXX)
```

that really doesn't do anything. The package VTK is correctly found under `/usr/lib/vtk-5.8/VTKConfig.cmake`. This file includes a number of statements of the type

```
ADD_LIBRARY(foobar SHARED IMPORTED)
```

to indicate that the shared library `libfoobar.so` will need to be linked in executables.

Upon creating Makefiles using the above script, however, CMake will complain that

```
CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/lib/vtk-5.8/VTKTargets.cmake:244 (ADD_LIBRARY):
  ADD_LIBRARY called with SHARED option but the target platform does not
  support dynamic linking.  Building a STATIC library instead.  This may lead
  to problems.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/vtk-5.8/VTKConfig.cmake:200 (INCLUDE)
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindVTK.cmake:73 (FIND_PACKAGE)
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (FIND_PACKAGE)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it
```

What does this warning mean and how is it dealt with?

This is a Linux system with CMake 2.8.9. While this error message appears for all packages that contain `ADD_LIBRARY(foobar SHARED IMPORTED)`, VTK-5.8 is used as an example here.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

PROJECT sets some important variables about the plarform.

Don't call FIND_* modules before setting a name to PROJECT.

Comment: Great answer, however not applicable in case the `FIND_*` command is in a toolchain file. See https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=15999

Comment: This helped me out, I am using QT and called `find_package` before `project`, I flipped them and the error went away.

Answer (score 13):

This error message occurs when the CMake global property **TARGET_SUPPORTS_SHARED_LIBS** is set false and you use a shared library. See `Source/cmAddLibraryCommand.cxx` line 100 in the CMake source.

This shouldn't normally occur unless you are cross compiling for a very basic system (embedded OS).

I suspect that either this is a bug in the latest version of CMake or you have not configured CMake correctly.

Comment: Indeed. For some reason, `TARGET_SUPPORTS_SHARED_LIBS` isn't set on this Linux machine here. Explicitly setting `SET_PROPERTY(GLOBAL PROPERTY TARGET_SUPPORTS_SHARED_LIBS TRUE)` does away with the warnings.