# CLion unable to recognize OpenCV libraries (no IntelliSense)

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, cmake, clion

I am trying to solve this thing for quite some time. After a few hours I just decided to post a question because I am out of ideas. I imported a project into CLion with the CMakeLists.txt already inside. I am working on ubuntu and have the newest cmake version (3.5.something, OpenCV is 2.4.x). I use clion just for the IntelliSense, I wont be using it for the compilation anyway (I use terminal for that).

By opening the project I get following warning messages (which I somehow succeeded to reduce to warnings). This happens for every add_library line in OpenCVModules.cmake (I post just one of them):

```
CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/local/share/OpenCV/OpenCVModules.cmake:53 (add_library):
  ADD_LIBRARY called with SHARED option but the target platform does not
  support dynamic linking.  Building a STATIC library instead.  This may lead
  to problems.
```

Has anyone got ideas?

@CMakeLists.txt

```
# OpenCV:
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIR})
IF(OpenCV_FOUND)
  MESSAGE(STATUS "OpenCV_LIBS = ${OpenCV_LIBS}")
ELSE(OpenCV_FOUND)
  MESSAGE(STATUS "OpenCV_LIBS not found!")
ENDIF(OpenCV_FOUND)

project(cvtask1a)
file(GLOB SOURCES ${SOURCE_WILDCARDS})
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cgcvcommon)
add_executable(cvtask1a ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(cvtask1a ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Comment: Have you tried to google for error message? E.g., [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264299/cmake-on-linux-target-platform-does-not-support-dynamic-linking) ask about the same error message. And its [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25844355/3440745) suggests to check that you don't forget about `project()` call before `find_package(OpenCV)`.

Comment: Can you post what your CmakeLists.txt looks like? By the way, I didn't downvoted your question, on the contrary, upvoted for it to offset the -1 :) You are welcome.

Comment: are you using `find_package` in your CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: Yap, did try both of these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711109/could-not-find-module-findopencv-cmake-error-in-configuration-process
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264299/cmake-on-linux-target-platform-does-not-support-dynamic-linking

The second one, I'm not actually sure on what "Source" folder is he referring to.

@DarienPardinas Haha thanks :) I'll edit my post now and include cmakelists.txt

And yeah I tried putting project on top and all I get then is following error message

Comment: CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (add_executable):
  add_executable called with incorrect number of arguments


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "cvtask1a" which is not built by
  this project.

Comment: So you have moved `project()` call to the top, and original problem disappears. Problem with `add_executable()` is **unrelated** (in short: your `SOURCES` variable is empty).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake on Linux: "target platform does not support dynamic linking"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264299/cmake-on-linux-target-platform-does-not-support-dynamic-linking)

Comment: What should be in my sources var?? Anyway I was unable to find the file that guy suggested. I could only find it online in cmake repo...