# vcpkg glfw with cmake gives LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x338

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2022, glfw

Im trying to create a project with a glfw and cmake but for some reason when i try to build it with cmake it just says that:

```
my_path_to\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\debug\bin\glfw3.dll : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x338
```

Also probably unrelated but there's another warning that im not part of

```
1> [CMake] CMake Warning (dev) at my_path_to/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/share/glfw3/glfw3Targets.cmake:58 (add_library):
1> [CMake]   ADD_LIBRARY called with SHARED option but the target platform does not
1> [CMake]   support dynamic linking.  Building a STATIC library instead.  This may lead
1> [CMake]   to problems.
```

my cmake files

```
#Top-level
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED On)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS Off)

find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED)
find_package(VulkanHeaders REQUIRED)
find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)



project(vulkan_hype VERSION 1.0.0) #name of your project

enable_testing()
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  # Specify the commit you depend on and update it regularly.
  URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/dddb219c3eb96d7f9200f09b0a381f016e6b4562.zip
)

set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)
enable_testing()
include(GoogleTest)

#myownstuff
add_subdirectory(src)
```

And the other one

```
#src

add_executable(AnchorApp
    main.cpp
)

target_include_directories(AnchorApp PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/..)
target_link_libraries(AnchorApp 
PRIVATE 
    glfw
    Vulkan::Vulkan
    Vulkan::Headers
)
```

this mistake was before and after I upgraded glfw package with --no-dry-run, so file is probably not corrupted.

But i still tried to remove a reinstall the package using vcpkg

lines to link glfw with cmake i took from
https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build_guide.html#build_link_cmake_package
in "With CMake and installed GLFW binaries"

Comment: I don't know much about CMake but if you are trying to link to a DLL you are doing something wrong, DLLs are found at run time not link time. Usually you reference a DLL from your program by using an *import library* which will have a .lib extension. And yes the other warning message seems highly relevant.

Comment: john, i dont directly link .dll or .lib. this stuff is not under my control when i use find_packages() (or at least i have no idea how to). For example Vulkan with vcpkg worked just fine. 
Could not find a reasong why vcpkg version of glfw didn't work for me, even though all examples i saw online did it exactly as i am. 
So the only solution that worked is that i build glfw myself using FetchContent. Im gonna leave question open, because i would prefer to not rebuild glfw every time i might need to clean rebuild my project and hope that someone knows what is exactly wrong in my solution

Comment: `find_package` shouldn't be called before the `project()`. This is described in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25844355/3440745) to the duplicate question.

Comment: @passsterf I didn't mean to say that you are 'directly' linking to a DLL, but the error message makes it clear that is in fact what is happening.